# Unable to add bone in Object Mode

Tags: armature, bones, object-mode

I'm trying to add bones to my two sphere objects, but even though I'm in object mode I can't add any bones. When I mouse over Armatures, I do not get any options to add bones at all. Can someone please let me know what I might be doing wrong? Thanks
[image: No bone option available]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This option adds an armature (with one bone) to your scene. You need to set the armature in edit mode to add bones. Toggle Show Overlays on the top right to see them.